# Strategy for developing and testing an SDK that will reside in the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, sdk, gac

I am developing an SDK for internal use at our company.  It will not be deployed (in SDK form, it will deploy as a runtime included with our products) outside of the company.  Other development groups will use this SDK to develop products and will get the SDK via setup (they will not pull source or binaries from source control).  As part of the setup, the SDK assemblies will be put on the target machine and they will also be installed in the GAC.  When a product is deployed, the SDK's "runtime" msm will be used to install the SDK's assemblies in the GAC.

So, each developer will install the SDK on their machine.  When they want to add a reference, they will browse to the install location of the SDK (or get it via the .NET tab on the Add References dialog if we decide to register the assemblies).  When they run the product they are developing, the assemblies will be resolved from the GAC.

That all seems pretty reasonable.

My question is about the best way for me, as the SDK developer, to work.  I will primarily be working on the SDK.  So, in addition to writing code for the SDK, I will be writing test code, test applications, samples, etc.  Is it better to write the tests against the "installed" SDK (i.e. reference the assemblies from their "installed" location, make sure that the assemblies are installed in the GAC so that when the tests (etc) run they are resolving from the GAC just like they will in real life?)  If I work this way, then as I work on the SDK, if I make a change, I will need to make sure that the modified assembly is in the GAC.

In addition to working on the SDK, I may also contribute to actual product features which might, in turn, utilize functionality in the SDK.  Again, it seems that I should do my work against the "installed" SDK so that I am using the same version as everyone else.

Maybe I am overcomplicating this, but I feel a little confused over the whole issue of managing the work being done (by me) locally on the SDK, running/testing against the "as deployed" assemblies (GAC), and how/if to transition between the two.  Part of my problem is that I have a good amount of experience in application development working on "big" projects where I have not had to deal with these kinds of issues (deployment, build process, etc).  That is, I have always been a consumer of any internally developed SDKs, not a producer (or producer/consumer).  I have also only recently transitioned from C++/COM/VB6 to .NET development.  For what it's worth, I will be developing primarily in C# and will be developing (or contributing to) class libaries and WCF services.

I did find this link from here at SO about testing issues when working with GAC deployed assemblies:

[Testing code in GAC deployed assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694504/testing-code-in-gac-deployed-assemblies)

But I'm not sure that it helped me that much.

Anyway, thanks for any tips or ideas that anyone is able to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overcomplicating matters.  There is no functional difference between loading assemblies from the local app bin directory vs loading from the GAC.  For unit testing, go with the simplest and fastest solution: just run the tests referencing the SDK assemblies that were copied into the test app's local bin directory by the build process.

You should have a different testing step that exercises loading an application that references your SDKs that reside in the GAC to make sure you don't have any signature issues, but this is more of a system-wide integration test that should be run before release and after any install configuration changes.  Since the chances of screwing up your GAC installation are relatively small, it doesn't need to be monitored all the time, IMO.

The less install prerequisites you place on the dev environment, the less time it will take for each dev to get set up on a new machine.  Keeping a clean and simple dev environment is good for general dev sanity, but it's particularly important when you have multiple devs who each work with multiple VMs for development and testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did feel like I was probably overcomplicating things, but this particular work situation/environment is still new to me so I am still trying to find my way.